# what is the logs default location locally and remotely

Tags: sas, remote-server

Could you tell me the default location of the  logs

Comment: I looked through your question stack and you have a lot of questions where it seems that you do have not put in any effort to actually find the answer yourself. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. I googled on `sas log location` and the first hit led me to the official documentation about logging in `SAS`.

Comment: Hi, I have googled the same and it takes me to the documentation., and also I do my research before I put a question here.
I have gone through the documentations and what I see is about the spawners. But I want to know how is it saved locally and also where and when we do the remote submit(on a unix server).

Comment: And that is what I'm pointing at. It is impossible for me as a reader to know what kind of reasearch you have conducted if you don't write it down.

Comment: Ok. I would do that... 
So I am not able to find the location for this at this point.. do you have any suggestion for me?

Comment: Hey User, did you see my answer? It shows how to direct logs where you want on either local or remote SAS. Let me know if you need to know more or accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are after logs generated from your SAS program that you just submitted in interactive mode to your local or remote server, it will not be saved to any physical location unless you tell it do to so (see below for how to do it). The logs will be showed in your log window (for SAS Base) or Projec Log/Step Log if your are working from SAS EG. Other SAS applications have other locations.

If you need your program log to be saved in a specific location with specific filename, you need to use PROC PRINTTO.

Let say, you have a program that puts "Hello Worlds" in to your log and you are working on unix.

Example:

```
PROC PRINTTO log="/home/work/log.log";
QUIT; 

DATA _null_; 
put "Hello World"; 
RUN; 

/* you need to run empty PROC PRINTTO in order to direct the logs into
defaul location (your interactive session window */
PROC PRINTTO; 
QUIT;
```

RESULT LOG printed to a file log.log:

```
NOTE: PROCEDURE PRINTTO used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds


19         
20         DATA _null_;
21         put "Hello World";
22         RUN;

Hello World
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds


23         
24         PROC PRINTTO;
25         QUIT;
```